# Equivalent to OCaml variants in Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures, ocaml, variant

Is there a way to create in Ruby something like the OCaml [variants](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html)?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
type status =
| sent of DateTime * Location
| paid of DateTime
| new
```

But I can't figure how to do this in a a clean, safe and concise way.

I have an `Order` class with a `status` member. Possible value for this field are `sent`, `paid` or `new`. Some of the member of my class are set and used only for some states of `status`.

```
class Order
    field :status # can be :sent, :paid or :new
    field :paid_at # DateTime
    field :sent_at # DateTime
    filed :sent_to # Symbol
end
```

It work well but in term of design I'm wondering if there is a better way to do that. For exemple, here the `sent_to` field can be accessed even when status is not `:sent`. Another problem with this design is readability: expect the members name, nothing indicate that `:sent_to` is linked to the `:sent` state while `send_at` is linked to `:paid`. In this exemple, readability is ok because there is only few fields linked to a state and fields names are obvious but I'm not sure it will still be the case with bigger classes.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit it to include more detail. What is your input like? What is the result that you want? If you "can't figure how to do this in a a clean, safe and concise way" to do this, it would be very helpful for us to see what you've attempted, even if it's not clean, safe, or concise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/128421. While we'd like to help, your question is in need of more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In languages that don't have a native support for sum types, the usual method is to use a product type with a tag and all the fields that appear in the sum type. In your case this would give:

```
type tag = Sent | Paid | New
type status = {tag: tag; date : date_time; location: location}
```

Here the field `date` is meaningful only if `tag` has the value `Sent` or `Paid` and the field `location` is meaningful only if `tag` has the value `Sent`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, probably someone can come up with something better than this. This is not as *clean, safe, concise* as it would be in OCaml. Ruby is meant to be strong on other things, or at least this is what I like to say to myself. :-)

```
module Status
  Sent = Struct.new(:date, :location)
  Paid = Struct.new(:date)
  Processing = Class.new
end

status = Status::Sent.new("right now dude!", "location unknown")

case status
when Status::Sent
  puts status.date, status.location
when Status::Paid
  puts status.date
when Status::Processing
  puts "Processing things"
else
  puts "I don't know what is going on"
end
```

As you see, you use duck typing instead of statically checking types and you substitute pattern matching with the case statement

Comment: Checking something's class is not duck typing. Duck typing is when you only care which methods something responds to, not what its class is.

Answer (score 1):

Its doable, here's an great example done by really good OCaml programmers but in Python (Python should be close enough to ruby)

https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/python/adt.py